# drop down list not post back-javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a tabpanel with a dropdownlist control on the 4th tab but when I select a item, the **postback** not occur even **autopostback** property is true. Is there any way to **postback** the page when item is selected?

I think this use the javascript code to postback the drop down list please suggest.

Any ideas ?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlrole" runat="server" Width="151px" AutoPostBack="True" 
                  onselectedindexchanged="ddlrole_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

code behind is:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //code goes here
    }
 }

 protected void ddlrole_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    st = int.Parse(ddlrole.SelectedValue);
 }
```

`ddlrole_SelectedIndexChanged` is not fire when an item is selected from drop down list?

I use the javascript code to prevent this tab to return to first tab:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#tabContainer").tabs();
    var currTab = $("#<%= HFCurrTabIndex.ClientID %>").val();
    $("#tabContainer").tabs({ selected: currTab });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Without that script, does that DropDownList postback to server?

Comment: What tabs are you using? Also, is there something else you are using with Javascript on it? I got a similar problem but I was using a FreeTextBox control.

Comment: Could you add more asp code regarding the tabs? Are you using asp:UpdatePanel?

Comment: without that script this tab(i.e 4th tab) postback to previous tab(i.e 3rd tab).. @Win

Comment: not using update panel..we want drop down list postback when item is selected @nmat

Comment: Win is trying to help you narrow down the problem by eliminating the JavaScript. If you remove the JavaScript, does the postback happen (try it)?

Comment: yes postback occur when remove the JavaScript..but it goes to another tab when this script remove..we need this script to remain on this tab @jadarnel27

Comment: @Bhavnish where are you calling the javascript?

Comment: @nmat calling javascript in head tag